# Unity Glitches and throws a lot of errors when i run this Code

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So i made a program which will simulate earth spinning around the sun.
I wrote some code which will stop earth spinning every solstice/equinox and switch to a scene which explains what that specific solstice/equinox is.

When I run the code Unity Glitches and throws some errors in the console

See the below recording to see what happens when i run the game(in unity)

[Click Here for the recording](https://youtu.be/wCYW8IuV_3c)

Also I get the loop of the same errors See the screenshot below for the errors:

[This is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xsPv0.png)

This is the code I wrote:

```
    using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class CompDel : MonoBehaviour
{
        public Text TimeText;

        public float Timer = 70;
        // Start is called before the first frame update
        void Start()
        {

        }

        // Update is called once per frame
        void Update()
        {
            Timer = Timer - 1 * Time.deltaTime;


            if (Timer < 40)
            {
                this.GetComponent<RotateAround>().enabled = false;
                this.GetComponent<RR1>().enabled = false;

            };

            
            if (Timer < 40)
            {
                
                SceneManager.LoadScene("SSScene");
            }

            

            
            if (Timer < 30)
            {
                SceneManager.LoadScene("MainScene");
            }


            if (Timer < 0)
            {
                this.GetComponent<RotateAround>().enabled = false;
                this.GetComponent<RR1>().enabled = false;

            };

            
            if (Timer < 0)
            {
                SceneManager.LoadScene("AESCENE");
            }
        } 
}
```

So what am i doing Wrong?

Pls reply soon.I have to sumbit this in a couple days

:D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's more than one thing wrong with your program, but from the video you submitted the main problem is that the contents of all your if statements are running on every update loop (so dozens of times a second).

When the value of `Timer` is for example 25, your program loads the scene *SSScene*, then *MainScene* within the span of a few milliseconds. Since you're not loading the scenes additively, every call to load scene effectively replaces the scene currently loaded with a new scene. And this happens maybe 60 times a second. That explains the glitch you see on screen.

If the intent was to switch from one scene to another when timer goes below a certain value, you need to reorganize your code so that the scene only switches onces. You can do that by using else statements and keeping track of what scene is currently loaded.

Add in your class a `private string currentScene`, then in your update function:

```
if (Timer < 0 && currentScene != "AESCENE"){
    SceneManager.LoadScene("AESCENE");
    currentScene = "AESCENE";
} else if (Timer < 30 && currentScene != "MainScene"){
    SceneManager.LoadScene("MainScene");
    currentScene = "MainScene";
} else if (Timer < 40 && currentScene != "SSScene"){
    SceneManager.LoadScene("SSScene");
    currentScene = "SSScene";
} ...etc
```